# Serilog LogEntries sink deprecated

Tags: serilog, logentries

The LogEntries sink for Serilog has been deprecated and we are using this in our production applications.  Does anyone have any suggestions to resolve this issue?

https://github.com/serilog-archive/serilog-sinks-logentries

Comment: Hi Mike! The project has been archived because there isn't anyone currently able to review/merge patches, or keep the sink up-to-date with changes in LogEntries. If you are a LogEntries customer, requesting that LogEntries take over maintenance of the sink might do the trick (I don't have a contact at LogEntries, but would be glad to help them). Alternatively, building/publishing the code yourself (internally or through a public fork) would work. HTH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LogEntries is rebranded/replaced by InsightOps. So you should use the InsightOps sink: https://github.com/PureKrome/serilog-sinks-insightops

Link regarding the initial rebranding: https://www.rapid7.com/about/press-releases/rapid7-announces-insightops/